How can I annotate variadic generics in Python?
I have a generic class:
class A[T]:
  pass

And a function that extracts T from A:
def func[T](arg: A[T]) -> T:
  pass

Now my function can accept *args and extract all Ts from all of the given As. Each 'T' may of course be different.
Something along these lines:
def func[*Ts](*args: A[*Ts]) -> *Ts:
    pass

How do I annotate it correctly?
Unfortunately the TypeVarTuple does not seem to support it.
ATM I'm using many overloads of different amount of args, and a general *args: A -> Any for 6 or more args.

So something like x : A[int] = ...; y: A[float] = ...; func(x, y) == (1, 3.14)? I know you can specify *args: *Tuple[*Ts] and capture the runtime types of the arguments in a TypeVarTuple. I don't know if you can capture T1, T2, etc from *Tuple[A[T1], A[T2], ...].

@chepner precisely. I wonder if I should send this to the python-ideas mailing list. It's a difficult one to implement. Just thought it may be possible in some weird technique I haven't thought of.

The main issue would be differentiating between A accepting *Ts and a repeating A of different T upon writing using that syntax.

https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216
